DCDC layout review
Here my schematic:

It should withstand an output current of 1 A with an input voltage within 14..17V.
The loads are an MCU, a DC motor and a couple of solenoids. The power supply comes from a LiPo battery. This is my layout:

the large track on the bottom-right comes from the unregulated power input, the +12V track on the bottom-left goes to the circuit.
Here what I learnt reading other questions and docs:

keep the GND planes (top and bottom) as whole as possible
keep the traces as short as possible
do not cross the feedback signal (the L shaped track) with other wires
make power traces as large as possible to reduce inductance

Do you see any evidence of mistakes in my design? Or something that could be improved?

One nit-pick, which I'm not sure how relevant it is, would be to rotate the inductor counter clock-wise by 90° so that the feedback trace gets shorter. 140k means it's a sensitive signal which may or may not be sensitive to EMI (from the regulator itself in particular).

It would probably be better to have your output capacitors flipped 180°, so their ground connection is towards the switch. This is relatively minor, though. Make sure there's good filtering between your MCU load and your motor load.

You should follow the recommendations in the data sheet. It seems quite clear.

At least the output caps are on the other side of inductor than from where you take the output. Thus the feedback is taken from far away of the output caps.
So the layout does not resemble the datasheet layout example for best practices.

Sorry, not sure to understand. It's correct to pick the fb far away from the output caps or should I arrange in order to pick it close to those caps?

The flow of current should be from inductor to output caps, from that point to feedback and output load. Now the current flows into different direction if inductor charges the caps or load discharges the caps, and the feedback is taken from a ripply place instead of from stable place of the capacitors.

Ok, got it. So I need to swap the side of the output caps and place them near the fb signal

@Mark Best to follow datasheet example. It helps to think about loops of the switching currents flowing and the voltage swings of the nodes.

I disagree with the other answer, your output capacitor placement and feedback routing is fine. It would be marginally better as descirbed in that answer.
However, your main problem is not enough input capacitance. Put a couple more parallel MLCC caps, hopefully more on the order of 1-10uF. This will help with stability and, more realistically, EMI.
A ferrite bead on the input wiring would help, too, but is not always necessary.  Buck converters have discontinuous input current so input capacitance is most important placement--but there is no ideal capacitor so no matter what you do there will be some voltage noise (and current noise from input wiring) on that node, hence the suggestion for a ferrite bead.
On that note, you should connect the GND of the IC to the GND of the input capacitor C2. RIght now it goes through a via but you could force a small trace there -- now your GNDs are tied through vias to the plane, but also on the same layer, minimizing inductance.
Edit -- just noticed your input capacitor C2 only has one little via to connect to the GND plane (and thus to the IC, as currently laid out).  add a couple more vias in that area. AS much as you can fit, honestly, without making total swiss cheese of the area.  2-3 is GREAT and sufficient for most designs.
